How to incorporate greek symbols on x-axis ticks in R plot programmatically?
nothing seems to be working, I have tried parse, bquote, paste etc. Also tried other Q&A by other users. There was one answer using do.call that did not work for me either.
I have ended up writing them by hand but this does not seem very ideal situation, I feel like this should be very simple but somehow I am not able to get them to work. I am trying to do this in base R but if there is any other solution such as ggplot that should work as well. Here is my code
n = 1e6
d_norm <- rnorm(n)
d_norm_den <- density(d_norm)
plot(d_norm_den, ylab = NA, lwd = 3, main = NA, xlab = NA, xaxt = "n")
mtext(text = "Empirical Rule", side = 3, line = 2, cex = 2, font = 4)
mtext(text = "(Normal distribution)", side = 3, line = 0.5, cex = 1.25, font = 1)
axis(side = 1, at = seq(-3,3), 
     labels = expression(mu*'-'*3*sigma,mu*'-'*2*sigma,mu*'-'*1*sigma,mu,mu*'+'*1*sigma,mu*'+'*2*sigma,mu*'+'*3*sigma))

it generates plot like this below

is there any way I can create this labels argument in the axis() function automatically?

You can use an lapply to create a list of expressions
vals <- -3:3
labels <- as.expression(lapply(vals, function(x) 
  if (x==0) quote(mu) else if (x<0) bquote(mu-.(abs(x))*sigma) else bquote(mu+.(x)*sigma)))

And then use that with
axis(side = 1, at = seq(-3,3), labels = labels)

The general case seems to be more characters but should scale to other ranges.
